# how to search a file name in pycharm?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

How does one search for that file without manually looking in every directory and without making a script to do it?

when working on a large codebase one may have difficulty finding a file mentioned in a stack trace.

Comment: Try Looking into this Docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Shift+N and select Files tab and type what you are looking for

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-finding-a-file-class-or-symbol-by-name.html#navigate-to-symbol